# How can I stop plothover and plotclick events when using plotselecting event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, selection, flot

I need a way to unbind these functions when the `plotselecting` event fires, so the tooltip does not display when selecting.

I have tooltips set up like this:

```
$.fn.useToolTip = function (){
   $(this).bind("plothover", function (event, pos, item){                         
      //tooltip code
   });
}
```

and the function is used like this:

```
$("#panel").useToolTip();
```

I also have a lockable points function that uses the `plotclick` event in the same manner.

I am using jquery 1.3.2, the minimum for flot, so I cannot use .on() or .off(). How can I make a way to silence the hover and click when making my selection?

Comment: You can use a global variable that indicates whether the `plotselecting` handler is active. Than check that variable before executing the tooltip code.

Comment: Ah that could work. Thank you, I'll give it a try.